# Calculus Twice Differentiable Function Tangent Line Equation Problem Help

Tags: calculus, derivatives, tangent-line

Question: Suppose that $f(x)$ is a twice-differentiable function such that $\lim_{x\to 3}\dfrac{12x-36}{3f(x)-6}=-1$. Find the equation of the tangent line to $f(x)$ at $x=3$.

So I know a couple things: because f(x) has to be twice-differentiable, it must be to the ^2. Another thing I know is that since the derivative of th top is 12, the denominator has to be negative (or at least, 6*(something) has to be negative -12). Is the answer really as simple as -2, so f(x) is -2x^2 ? It can't be that simple because you also have to incorporate the product rule right? May I please have some help? I'm stuck. Thanks!

Comment: Start by simplifying. Then remember the not-so-common definition of a derivative

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)$ doesn't necessarily have to be any polynomial or any specific kind of function.

Since the numerator equals $0$, the limit equal $-1$ then the denominator must equal $0$

$f(3) = 2$

And since both numerator and denominator equal 0 we can apply L'Hopital's rule.

$\lim_\limits{x\to 3} \frac {12x - 36}{3f(x) - 6} =  \lim_\limits{x\to 3} \frac {\frac{d}{dx}(12x - 36)}{\frac {d}{dx} 3f(x) - 6} = \frac {12}{3f'(3)} = -1$

$f'(3) = -4$

And now since you know $f(3)$ and $f'(3)$ you can find the equation of the line tangent to $f(x)$ at $x = 3$

$(y-2) = -4(x-3)$

Comment: It's much prettier than my solution when you're using the 'advanced' technique of L'Hopital's Rule, but my concern is that they might not have learned it yet. But otherwise... nice job!

Answer (score 1):

We are given $\lim_{x\to3} \frac{12x-36}{3f(x)-6} = -1$. Simplify by dividing out the common factor, 3.

$$\lim_{x\to3} \frac{4x-12}{f(x)-2} = -1$$
`You can pull a common factor out of a multiple: lim C*L = C*lim L, C is a constant, L is a function.`
$$4\cdot\lim_{x\to3} \frac{x-3}{f(x)-2} = -1$$
$$\lim_{x\to3} \frac{x-3}{f(x)-2} = -\frac14$$
`The limit of a fraction is equal to its reciprocal: if lim A/B = C, then lim B/A = 1/C.`
$$\lim_{x\to3} \frac{f(x)-2}{x-3} = -4$$

The not-so-common definition of a tangent slope is $m = \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$.

If we just plug the limit equation in to the slope formula identify variables and etc., we get that $a=3, f(a) = 2,$ and $f'(a) = -4$.
Use point-slope formula now: $y-y_0 = m(x-x_0)$ --> $$y-2 = -4(x-3)$$
$$y=-4x+14$$